# Segmentation fault due to strlen_sse2()

Tags: c, pointers, memory, heap-memory

I am using an array of char pointers.

```
#define MAXFIELDS 100
#define MAX_LENGTH 245

char  *dex_data[MAXFIELDS];  //declared globally.
```

I have used this dex_data array in so many functions. I allocate memory in main function like this

```
 dex_data = malloc(sizeof(char *)*MAXFIELDS);  

 int p;

 for(p=0; p < MAXFIELDS ; p++)
    dex_data[p] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_LENGTH);
```

Getting segmentation fault every time. I tried to check the error through GDB. It says

```
 #0  0x00007fb0a91b2b71 in __strlen_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Did I allocate memory wrongly, or did I try to allocate larger memory?
I don't know the reason. Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code where you are getting the error. There's a good chance you've got a string missing a `'\0'`, you've forgotten to allocate something (here you allocate space for 100 pointers, but then only allocate 20 strings), or you've overwritten a pointer so it points somewhere random.

Comment: The memory allocation code you show so far looks OK. It's a bit odd you're only allocating pointers for a hard-coded 20 entries of `dex_data` and not doing `for (p=0; p < MAXFIELDS; p++) ...`. It leads to some suspicion whether your code elsewhere (not shown) is honoring this and not accessing `dex_data[i]` for some `i` 20 or higher.

Comment: I have used this dex_data[] at so many places, in strcmp() in strlen(), didn't do anything else. anyways one example for you.              if ( strlen(dex_data[6]) > 0 ) {
                 free_qty = atoi(dex_data[6]);
              }
              else {
                 free_qty = 0;
              }

Comment: It's unclear what code caused the segfault from your question. But it's possible, for example, for `strlen(dex_data[6]) > 0` to cause a segfault if a proper zero-terminated string wasn't written to the location pointed to by `dex_data[6]` and it was length < MAX_LENGTH.

Comment: Hi @lurker, I haven't used dex_data for more than 10 times.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You could use it just once and get a segfault if it has the issue I described. You need to show code for how you set the strings pointed to by `dex_data[i]` entries, and how you're referencing them. The problem isn't in how you're allocating them. The problem is in how you're using them.

Comment: I could be remembering things wrongly, but I'm pretty sure that strlen_sse2() requires that the memory be aligned on 16 byte boundaries. Nothing in your allocation accounts for this.

Comment: Here is the [link](http://ideone.com/zGU8bf) to check my code. I need to pass the file while running. For security reasons I can't post the entire code, but I post the code where dex_data is used. So, I need to terminate each and every array ??? Is that it? How can terminate the array? In a normal way ?

Comment: @Nani "Here is the link to check my code" - That's not how SO works! Read [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: What have you done to try to debug the code? Since you are on Linux, running `gdb <your-app-name>` then `run` should drop you into the debugger when the program crashes, and `backtrace` will show you the call tree. You should see what line in your code is causing the problem, and if you are still not sure, please report the stack trace and the code around where the crash happens.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char  *dex_data[MAXFIELDS];
```

Is an array that already has `MAXFIELDS` amount of `char*` pointers on the stack. It is not assignable. However, here:

```
dex_data = malloc(sizeof(char *)*MAXFIELDS);
```

You are trying to assign to it. That is undefined behavior.

Simply delete that line. You do not need (nor are you allowed) to allocate memory for `dex_data`.

Side-note: assigning to an array type should at least give you a compile warning. It seems you're using a very old compiler and you should probably upgrade.

Comment: I removed the line you said, and still segmentation fault. I am using gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11) version on putty. I didn't get any warning. But I got same error "__strlen_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6" like I got before.

Comment: @Nani Then something else is causing the segfault. The code you posted is perfectly fine after removing the offending line.

Comment: Program is fine everywhere, except this dex_data. I don't know which is causing the error. Am I using larger memory for this dex_data buffer?

Comment: @Nani Why don't you create a new .c file with only those lines in it? Does it crash?

Comment: You can find my code [here](http://ideone.com/zGU8bf). That is the conclusion, I used dex_data[] like this. Or else any other kind of usage is there(about dex_data)?? We know it is a double pointer.